# Can't get second JavaFX stage to show?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a RDP client and I want to show a new stage while keeping the old one running. Unfortunately the second stage isn't coming up at all.

This is my stage:

```
public final class Remote extends Stage {

    private static final URL FXML = Remote.class
            .getResource("/conspire/remote.fxml");
    private static final Image ICON = new Image(Remote.class.getResource(
            "icon.png").toExternalForm());

    public static Remote create(String title) throws IOException {
        return new Remote(title);
    }

    private Remote(String title) throws IOException {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(FXML);

        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        setScene(scene);

        getIcons().add(ICON);
        setTitle(title);
        setResizable(true);
        centerOnScreen();

        show();
    }

}
```

And this is how I run it:

```
Remote.create(host + " (" + partner.getValue() + ") - Conspire");
```

The *create* method won't even invoke. If I add a sysout in there it won't print.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to create a new stage you must run it from within the JavaFX thread. You can do this easily with JavaFX's *Platform* tool. In your case:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    Remote.create(host + " (" + partner.getValue() + ") - Conspire");
});
```

Comment: The question says nothing about threading, and doesn't show the exception you would get if you invoked this from off the FX Application Thread.